# Selecting every 1st element with nth-of-type

Tags: html, css

I've got this HTML markup:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">1</div>
    <div class="child">2</div>
    <div class="child">3</div>
    <div class="child">4</div>
    <div class="child">5</div>
    <div class="child">6</div>
    <div class="child">7</div>
    <div class="child">8</div>
    <div class="child">9</div>
    <div class="child">10</div>

    <div class="child">1</div>
    <div class="child">2</div>
    <div class="child">3</div>
    <div class="child">4</div>
    <div class="child">5</div>
    <div class="child">6</div>
    <div class="child">7</div>
    <div class="child">8</div>
    <div class="child">9</div>
    <div class="child">10</div>

    <div class="child">1</div>
    <div class="child">2</div>
    <div class="child">3</div>
    <div class="child">4</div>
    <div class="child">5</div>
    <div class="child">6</div>
    <div class="child">7</div>
    <div class="child">8</div>
    <div class="child">9</div>
    <div class="child">10</div>
</div>
```

With these CSS properties:

```
.child {
    float: left;
    width: 10%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

As you can see, the classes with the content from 1 through 10 fill the screen in the `width`. And have a `background-color` of `red`.

I've got 3 of these, im going to call these 'rows'.

I have achieved to give every last item of the `rows` a `background-color`of `yellow` by doing this:

```
.child:nth-of-type(10n) {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

But whenever I try to do the same thing but then on the first item on every row, its not working:

```
.child:nth-of-type(1n) {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

How do I give every first item of a row a `background-color` aswell without creating other HTML elements.

**[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/jgueU/1/)**

Comment: is this you are looking for? http://jsbin.com/tofineji/1/edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `1n` means **each**.

```
.child:nth-of-type(10n+1) {
     background-color: green;
}
```

OR

```
.child:first-child, .child:nth-of-type(10n) + .child {
     background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, didnt know that. What does the second solution do then? Select the element underneath of `.child:nth-of-type(10n)`?

Comment: @Bas: both solutions do the same thing. `+` is `sibling` selector, it means `fire next sibling of each 10th element` - the same as `+1` in code above.

Comment: The second option not applying the green color of very first child. Is it right? No idea how Bas accept this.

Comment: not element in general, only next `.child`. If you want to fire next element and it doesn't matter what element, you can use `+ *`, where `*` means 'whatever'. More about sibling selector http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selectors/selector_adjacent.html

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai: thanks, I've added first child to the second, alternative, code.

Answer (score 2):

So you want to apply different color to the cells(0,11,21 and so on). Write your CSS like below. "N" will start from 0 and so on. It means (0*10 + 1), (1*10 + 1), (2*10 + 1). [More Details about the nth-of-type CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp)

```
 .child:nth-of-type(10n+1) {
  background-color: green;
 }
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/jgueU/2/)

Comment: Give some explanation to your code. Code only answers are not appreciated.

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen Thanks it worked. Can you give me some explaination please?

Comment: i just added some explanation for my answer.